# How to make R count the number of characters in an element in a dataframe?

Tags: r

```
structure(list(Switch = c("4", "3"), `1` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", 
NA), `2` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", NA), `3` = c("1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7", 
NA), `4` = c("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6", NA), `5` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", 
"1"), `6` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", NA
)), .Names = c("Switch", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Given the above data frame. I would like to make R count how many numbers there are in each element (separated by the comma). So for example an element that contains the list `1, 2, 3, 4` contains 4 numbers.

I want R to count how many total numbers there are per row before the switch year (column 1) and after the switch year.

Taking the first row as an example; the switch year is 4, in year 1 there are 4 different numbers, in year 2 there are 4, and 3 there are 6. So then R adds the total as 4+4+6=14 in a new column. Then it does the same with the years after the switch year (years 5 and 6) and outputs the total sum in a second new column.

In one of my searches, it was suggested to use the function `stri_extract_all_regex` in the `stringi` package, but I could only get it to work for one column/year and it also seemed to count `NA` values as well, which it shouldn't.

The expected output is given by the code below:

```
    structure(list(Switch = c("4", "3"), `1` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", 
NA), `2` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", NA), `3` = c("1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7", 
NA), `4` = c("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6", NA), `5` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", 
"1"), `6` = c("1, 2, 3, 4", NA
), `Before` = c("15", 0), `After` = c("8", 1)
), .Names = c("Switch", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "Before", "After"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: `lapply(df, stringi::stri_count_words)`?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper. I've updated the question to include the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

another `stringi` solution:

```
library(stringi)

df[c("before","after")] <-
  t(apply(df,1,function(x) {
    counts <- stri_count_words(x[-1])
    x <- as.numeric(x[1])
    c(sum(head(counts,x-1),na.rm=TRUE),
      sum(tail(counts ,-x),na.rm=TRUE))
  }))

#   Switch          1          2                3                4          5          6 before after
# 1      4 1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4     14     8
# 2      3       <NA>       <NA>             <NA>             <NA>          1       <NA>      0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringi)

df2 <- df
# Count words and coerce to numeric
df2[-1] <- lapply(df2[-1], stri_count_words)
df2[1]  <- lapply(df2[1], as.numeric)
# For each row, sum the number of words before (part1) and after (part2)
newcols <- 
apply(t(df2), 2, function(x){ 
  part1 <- x[-1][1:(x[1] - 1)]
  part2 <- x[-1][-(1:x[1])]
  list(before = sum(part1, na.rm = T),
       after  = sum(part2, na.rm = T))})


cbind(df, do.call(rbind, newcols))


#   Switch          1          2                3                4          5          6
# 1      4 1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4
# 2      3       <NA>       <NA>             <NA>             <NA>          1       <NA>
#   before after
# 1     14     8
# 2      0     1
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, there are a couple of minor hiccups,
Firstly, I think there a plus one added to the "before" column results and that is probably my fault since I had a mistake in the example output (except my mistake  was 14 instead of 15).

Secondly, the code outputs weird results for Switch values that are on the border of the column names. But more particularly, it miscalculates the "after" when we tried it on a bigger data frame with 11 Switch columns and 3 more columns before the Switch column.

Could you help tackle these?